# No module named 'importlib.metadata' even after installing it

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, modulenotfounderror

> File
> "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kodi_cli.py", line
> 3, in 
> import importlib.metadata ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

```
pip3 install kodi-cli --user
```

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple,
> https://www.piwheels.org/simple Requirement already satisfied:
> kodi-cli in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.9)
> Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.0 in
> /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from kodi-cli)
> (2.28.1) Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from
> requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.0->kodi-cli) (1.24.1) Requirement already
> satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in
> /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.0->kodi-cli) (2.0.4) Requirement already
> satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from
> requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.0->kodi-cli) (2018.8.24) Requirement already
> satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from
> requests<3.0.0,>=2.28.0->kodi-cli) (2.6)

```
kodi-cli -H host -P 8080 -u username -p password -C
```

I got the error at top so..

```
pip3 install importlib-metadata --user
```

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple,
> https://www.piwheels.org/simple Requirement already satisfied:
> importlib-metadata in
> /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (5.0.0) Requirement
> already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in
> /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> importlib-metadata) (3.10.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8" in
> /home/username/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from
> importlib-metadata) (3.10.0.0)

Still get the error.

```
python3 --version
```

> Python 3.7.3

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

> PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="10" VERSION="10 (buster)" VERSION_CODENAME=buster
> ID=raspbian ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

I'm scratching my head here.  Any help would be appreciated.

I suspect it might have to do with this code in the program kodi_cli.py

```
import importlib.metadata
import json
import logging
import os
import pathlib
import sys
import textwrap

import version as ver_info
from kodi_interface import KodiObj

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version("kodi-cli")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed what @cory-gross said in the comment and it worked for me. very minor detail indeed.

*"python 3.8 and up use importlib.metadata and below python 3.8 uses importlib_metadata."*

so in my case it became:

```
from importlib_metadata import packages_distributions
packages_distributions() # I wanted to see all distribution names and their import names
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
import importlib.metadata
```

write

```
from importlib_metadata import metadata
```

if importlib_metadata module is not installed then first install via

```
pip install importlib-metadata
```

detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59734959/19428695

Comment: I needed to do the reverse of this suggestion.

tldr; python 3.8 and up use importlib.metadata and below python 3.8 uses importlib_metadata.